# построения дерева на postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, рекурсия

Добрый день не могу разобраться в чем проблема, пытаюсь построить дерево. Запрос сам работает только до того времени пока Структурных подразделений не станет больше 10 когда меньше то все ок выводит когда больше все как то съезжает не могли бы подсказать что я делаю не так?
Вот мой запрос и схема таблицы.

```
WITH RECURSIVE Rec(DeptKod, PKod, DeptName, Path, Level) AS(   

SELECT DeptKod, PKod, cast(DeptName AS VARCHAR) AS  DeptName, cast(DeptKod AS VARCHAR) AS Path,1 
FROM Structural_Subdivision 
WHERE PKod IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT D.DeptKod, D.PKod, lpad(' ', 3*level) || D.DeptName,Path || cast(D.DeptKod AS VARCHAR), Level+1 
FROM Structural_Subdivision D 
INNER JOIN Rec R 
ON (D.PKod = R.DeptKod))
SELECT DeptKod, DeptName FROM Rec ORDER BY Path;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "Съезжает", если вы про поле DeptName, может у вас при выводе шрифт не моноширинный

Comment: вот ссылки. в первой ссылке 9 подразделений и все норм работает, а во  второй 10 подразделений и не работает так как надо. 1.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/19f075/1    2.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/169fb/1

Comment: так может быть ничего не съезжает, просто сортировка ломается, потому что 10 при сортировке строки идет сразу за 1 и перед 2. что бы этого избежать надо делать фиксированную длину id в строке по которой сортировка, т.е. что-бы DeptKod=1 выглядел скажем как 00001, т.е. делать lpad нулем до нужного кол-ва знаков

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/169fb/3

Comment: Mike, спасибо помогло)